# SQL returned unexpected result from join clause ,why

Tags: sql

you can find the whole scenario in the picture

thanks in advance
[image: Source data and expected outcome]

My SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    a.item_code, 
    a.rep_code,
    sum(t.sales_target),
    sum(a.actual)
FROM sales_target t   
    JOIN  sales_actual a
        ON a.item_code = t.item_code AND a.rep_code = t.rep_code 
GROUP BY 
    a.item_code, 
    a.rep_code
```

Comment: That's really good. Here is image => guess the query. Did you use aggregations like sum?

Comment: my sql select  a.item_code , a.rep_code ,sum(t.sales_target) , sum(a.actual)
from sales_target t   join  sales_actual a
on a.item_code = t.item_code and a.rep_code = t.rep_code 
group by a.item_code , a.rep_code

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a Cartesian product for each item code/rep, so the values are wrong.  One method is to use `union all` and then aggregate:

```
select ta.item_code, ta.rep_code,
       sum(ta.sales_target), sum(ta.actual)
from ((select item_code, rep_code, sales_target, 0 as actual
       from sales_target t
      ) union all
      (select item_code, rep_code, 0 as sales_target, actual
       from sales_actual a
      )
     ) ta
group by ta.item_code, ta.rep_code;
```